# How can compile a TypeScript module that imports supplementary Javascript source?

Tags: typescript, webpack, ace-editor

How can I update my `.ts` source code, type definitions, and/or webpack config to ensure the supplementary brace editor code is included in the build?

I'm building a browser app in TypeScript and using webpack to build it. I'd like to use the [brace editor](https://www.npmjs.com/package/brace) component that does not have an existing type definition file. I have the following barebones type file:

```
declare module brace {
    export interface ISession {
        setMode(mode:string);
    }

    export interface IEditor {
        getSession():ISession;
        setTheme(theme:string);
    }
}
export function edit(selector:string):brace.IEditor
```

this allows me to compile an app with the following source:

```
import * as Brace from 'brace';
...
editor = Brace.edit(someElement);
editor.getSession().setMode('ace/mode/javascript');
editor.setTheme('ace/theme/monokai');
```

The brace module documentation suggests using the following *Javascript* to create the editor:

```
var ace = require('brace');
require('brace/mode/javascript');
require('brace/theme/monokai');

var editor = ace.edit(someElement);
editor.getSession().setMode('ace/mode/javascript');
editor.setTheme('ace/theme/monokai');
```

The `require()` statements for the `mode` and `theme` seem to be necessary so that the builder (webpack in my case) know to pull in this source code.

How can I update my `.ts` source code, type definitions, and/or webpack config to ensure the session and mode code is included in the build? In my current setup, they are not, so brace makes network requests that I'd like to avoid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TypeScript will remove any require() statements whose values are not used in the emitted code.  So, once compiled from TS to JS, your require statements were gone and webpack didn't know to include those in the bundle.

To work around this, you could do something like this:

```
var braceDependencies = [
    require('brace/mode/javascript'),
    require('brace/theme/monokai')
];
```

But TS now has support for ["bare imports"](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What's-new-in-TypeScript#bare-import) when using ES6 so you can more cleanly do this:

```
import 'brace/mode/javascript';
import 'brace/theme/monokai';
```

And those *will* be emitted as is.